# Cómo puedo hacer test de clase con constantes en java

Tags: java, test, junit, testing, junit-4

Tengo una clase con constantes que me da cobertura 0 en sonar, no puedo hacer skipt a esta clase, de qué forma puedo hacer los test de esta clase con constantes?

```
public class Constants {

    public static final String QUERY_SEARCH_PART = "db1;SELECT GF_CUSTOMER_ID,GF_EMAILUSU_DESC,GF_PHONE_ID,GF_CUSTOMER_NAME,GF_GROUP_ID  FROM GJSX.T_GJSX_CUSTOMER ";

    @VisibleForTestings
    public static final String QUERY_SEARCH_PART_CATALOG =" TABLECATALOGO WHERE OPER.G_CONTRACT_ID=TABLECATALOGO.G_CONTRACT_ID ";
    public static final String GF_FIRST_NAME="GF_FIRST_NAME";
    public static final String G_CUSTOMER_ID="G_CUSTOMER_ID";
    public static final String G_COUNTRY_ID="G_COUNTRY_ID";


    public static final String DB1="db1;";

}
```

Comment: Me parece que no sería necesario realizar un test de esta clase.

Comment: No he probado. Si haces un test de una clase que use estas constantes, ¿no sale como cubierto?

Comment: No sale como cubierto :/